# Magento2: Social login error

Tags: magento2, facebook, app, social-buttons

I created one website app for facebook login, I added site url and App Id and Secret key but it getting error like

```
      You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.
```

Comment: can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31879804/you-are-not-logged-in-please-log-in-and-try-again?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @RamaChandran This is for android app? I want in magento

Comment: omg, i am sorry, i will check now.

Comment: it is not from magento. Can you please check properly configured https://www.sourcecoast.com/jfbconnect/docs/social-network-applications/facebook-application-setup

Comment: ok i  will check it